# Why to specify BUILD_HOST?

Tags: edeliver

When deploying to multiple nodes, shouldn't we build the project on each node? why specifying `BUILD_HOST` in config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project is built only on the build node, not on each node. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/boldpoker/edeliver#build-commands) :

> For build commands the following configuration variables must be set:
>
> - `APP`: the name of your release which should be built
> - `BUILD_HOST`: the host where to build the release
> - `BUILD_USER`: the local user at build host
> - `BUILD_AT`: the directory on build host where to build the release. must exist.
>
> **The built release is then copied to your local directory `.deliver/releases` and can then be delivered to your production servers by using one of the deploy commands.**